# VSTS Copy and Publish Build Artifacts copying the whole project instead of the necessary files

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to copy my build to a particular drop location. But instead of copying the some important files and directories it is copying all the solution file and directories there like .csproj files and .csfiles and also all the folders present there.
I only want to copy dlls(projects dlls and references dlls of the project) and some data Folders and files to drop location so that I can use them to execute my test cases. But it ends up copying the whole solution.

Below are the setting I am using to copy and publish build artifacts.

[image]
Can Anyone tell me how can it be done?

Note: when I tried to put $(build.sourcesdirectory)\bin in the copy root it gave me an error that "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null".

I also tried putting only **.dll in my contents but then it copies nothing. The folder created in drop location comes empty.

Comment: Try to use  `**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
!**\obj\**` as the pattern of contents.

Comment: I did tried this but it is giving me an empty folder in drop location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're telling it to publish `**/*test*.dll`, from the root of the build agent. That minmatch pattern is saying "find everything in every subfolder that matches *test*.dll", so the results you're getting aren't surprising.

What you probably want to do is specify the path to the binary output location of your test projects. Without seeing the structure of your code or what MSBuild variables you're providing/overriding, it's impossible to give more guidance. Look at the [documentation on pre-defined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch#predefined-variables) and that should give you some ideas.

In general, you want to set your output folder (via MSBuild arguments) to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, so only build outputs go there. Then you can use that as your Copy Root.

Comment: How can I set my output folder (via MSBuild arguments) to $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)? do I have to type $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) in MSBuild argument ?